# Atomic group in Markdown regex

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I'm looking into dflydev's **MarkdownParser**. 
In **doBlockQuotes** [line 1167](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-markdown/blob/master/src/dflydev/markdown/MarkdownParser.php#L1167), they use *Atmoic Group* on the whole expression. 
I know *Atmoic Grouping* but I don't understand how it helps here?

Why is this:

```
/
(                     # Wrap whole match in $1
    (?>
        ^[ ]*>[ ]?    # ">" at the start of a line
        .+\n          # rest of the first line
        (.+\n)*       # subsequent consecutive lines
        \n*           # blanks
    )+
)
/xm
```

Better than this:

```
/
(                     # Wrap whole match in $1
        ^[ ]*>[ ]?    # ">" at the start of a line
        .+\n          # rest of the first line
        (.+\n)*       # subsequent consecutive lines
        \n*           # blanks
)
/xm
```

Comment: If you understand atomic groups, you should understand how they help here as well.

Comment: I understand the examples [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) but not in this context.. what's the difference between the two expressions I gave?

Answer (score 4):

The `+` quantifier following the atomic group means the regular expression engine will try to match the pattern within the group one or more times. This differs from the second expression where the engine will only try to match the pattern once.

The `+` is not followed by the lazy modifier `?`, so it will match greedily, i.e. as many times as possible.

The grouping was probably made atomic because as well as making the group non-capturing, it prevents any backtracking after each complete match of the whole sub-expression.

If or once the `\n*` at the end of the group fails to match a newline,  because of the `+` the engine will start trying to match the group again from the beginning. If it fails to do so, then because the group is atomic, the existing match will be returned.

If the group was not atomic, the engine would backtrack to try a different way of matching what had just been successfully matched, before trying to match the start of the group again.

For example, if the last three characters matched were newlines, `\n*`, it would first give the last one up and try to match the start of the group again. When that failed it would give another newline up and try again, and so on.

The backtracking would continue to the `(.+\n)*` sequence and there, because of the flexibility of both what is matched by the `.` and of how many characters are matched by the `+` and `*`, there would be a great many ways in which the engine could match the pattern before trying to match further again.

The same part of a string could be matched by the whole sub-expression in many different ways and therefore there would be a massive amount of inefficient, time-consuming backtracking possible before the engine could be sure no further matching is possible.

The atomic group denotation means that this can be avoided.